# TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable | summernote integration in django admin (SOLVED)

Tags: django

I am trying to intregrate django-summernote in my blog post admin area.
when I set  `summernote_fields = ('description',)` and register to admin area, I am getting error like below :

```
 for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable
```

My  `admin.py` is given below :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
from .models import Blog


class BlogPostSummerNote(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('description',)

@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','author','publish','status')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}


admin.site.register(BlogPostSummerNote)
```

I can't able to figure this out . Can any one tell me why this is happening ??

**############# SOLUTION #################**

I Solved this problem by doing as below in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
from .models import Blog


@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogPostSummerNote(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','author','publish','status')
    summernote_fields = ('description',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma to wrap it in a tuple, so `summernote_fields = ('description',)`?

Comment: You also need to add the model, so `admin.site.register(SomeModel, BlogPostSummerNote)` (where you replace `SomeModel` with the model).

Comment: I wraped it but still the same error ..

Comment: `Blog` is my model which I have imported , when I do `admin.site.register(Blog,BlogPostSummerNote)` then it raises `AlreadyRegistered(msg)`

Comment: well that makes since since later you use `BLogAdmin`. So you should register one admin per model.

Comment: Yeap I know .. but I am confused how can I get rid of this problem ??...

Comment: yoo .. It Solved ... thanks for your help @WillemVanOnsem